# fprintf - specifying path

Tags: c++, file-io, printf

I am confused as to where exactly I should specify the path to a file when I am writing to a file using `fprintf`.

For example, a simple displaying of vector elements:

```
FILE * myFile;

char * name = new char[50];

strcpy( name, "myFile.txt" );

myFile = fopen( name, "w" );

for ( int k = 0 ; k < vector.size() ; k++ )
 {
   printf( myFile, "%i", vector[k] );    
 }

fprintf( myFile, "Success!" );

fclose( myFile );
```

If I wanted to write the elements out on the display, I should use:

```
std::cout << vector[k] << endl;
```

But what if I wanted to write the elements out to a file elsewhere, e.g.

```
C:/blahblah/myFile.txt
```

Where do I specify my path?

Thanks,

Comment: `fopen("C:/blahblah/myFile.txt", "W");` Don't know why you're bothering with that `strcpy`ing the name to another buffer business.

Comment: Oh, do you mean you want to use the `<<` syntax, but to a different file? Look at [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream).

Comment: Please do not use `strcpy()`. It is very insecure - if the input is large, it can overflow the destination and abort or even worse modify your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fopen` accepts also path, not just filename:

```
myFile = fopen("C:\\blahblah\\myFile.txt", "w");`
```

If you want to use the `<<` syntax, use C++ I/O streams instead.

```
ostream f("C:\\blahblah\\myFile.txt");
f << vector[k] << endl;
```